# Parse JSON string to class

Tags: c#, .net, json, parsing

I would parse JSON string received to my ReturnClass (collection of ReturnClass).

My JSON string :

```
[
    { "EmpId": 1, "Name": "Simone", "City": "Italy" },
    { "EmpId": 2, "Name": "Luca", "City": "Francia" },
    { "EmpId": 1, "Name": "Matteo", "City": "Inghilterra"},
    { "EmpId": 2, "Name": "Marco", "City": "Spagna" }
]
```

My ReturnClass :

```
public class ReturnClass   
{
    public int EmpId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
}
```

This is my code tath doesn't works.. Error of Parsing

```
HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(URL).Result;  // Blocking call! 
if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    string output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);

    JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ReturnClass>(output);             
}
```

Answer (score 2):

With this code:

```
string output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ReturnClass>(output);
```

You are:

- Reading the HTTP response as a string
- Serializing that string to a JSON string
- Deserializing that JSON string into one `ReturnClass`

Apart from the first step, which is merely unnecessary, that is all wrong. There is no need to read the content as a string yourself, you definitely don't want to serialize a JSON string to JSON again, and you're not looking for *one* `ReturnClass`, but a collection thereof.

You can simplify the code to this:

```
var dataFromJson = await client.ReadAsAsync<List<ReturnClass>>();
```

As an added bonus you won't have to do the deserialization yourself, the `HttpClient` can do that just fine.